# Django 1.4.18 dev server slow to respond under VirtualBox

Tags: python, django, virtualbox

We're running our development environment in a virtualbox Ubuntu LTS 12.04 guest, in Windows 7 host. We use ./manage.py runserver during development.

Recently we upgraded our Django version to latest (1.4.19) but noticed a very odd behaviour: requests coming from host machine take anything from 5-30s to serve, while requests from inside VM are served in less than a second, as they should be. The problem has been introduced in Django 1.4.18 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.7/releases/1.4.18/), all older releases work fast.

Using different browser in guest or host makes no difference. It also does not make any difference whether the requested resource is dynamic or static (we use the static app to serve static content during development).

What could cause this kind of behaviour? From the release notes it's not immediately clear to us.

Comment: Is DNS configured properly on the host?

Comment: Both host and guest point to the same DNS server, which is the wifi router. Both are able to perform DNS lookups.

Comment: Can you attach to the process with strace and post the output during a request?

Comment: Does it only apply to django development server? Try to configure django through nginx or other http server and see if it still happens.

Comment: @GwynBleidD as mentioned, it occurs only with django releases 1.4.18 and 1.4.19 (latest 1.4.x as of now). If we downgrade to 1.4.17 or anything older the problem is gone. We are trying to figure out what happened in 1.4.18 to cause this, but couldn't find an obvious reason to release notes.

Comment: I'm not asking about django version, but about way of deploying your app. Does it only happen on ./manage.py runserver or also via gunicorn/uwsgi/mod_wsgi and nginx/apache?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were trying to achieve. While that would be interesting to test, we don't have the time to start setting up an alternative dev environment. In production Apache (without VirtualBox of course) the problem does not exist, so as a work-around we have just downgraded the dev version to 1.4.17 for those who have to use a VM. We'll probably test your suggestion once we upgrade the major version, if the problem still persists then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wow I can't believe I finally managed to solve this. I had *exactly* the same issue and you put me on the right track by mentioning that it only appeared for version later than Django 1.4.17.

**Short solution:** add your gateway IPs to /etc/hosts in your guest machine, e.g:

```
10.0.2.2 10.0.2.2
```

**Long explanation:** Django 1.4.18 introduced the stripping of headers that contain underscores. That's harmless, but the `django.core.servers.basehttp.WSGIRequestHandler.get_environ` method was slightly altered. From 1.4.18 on, it relies on `wsgiref.simple_server.WSGIRequestHandler.get_environ`, which contains the line:

```
host = self.address_string()
```

`address_string` is a method from `BaseHTTPServer`:

```
 def address_string(self):
    """Return the client address formatted for logging.

    This version looks up the full hostname using gethostbyaddr(),
    and tries to find a name that contains at least one dot.

    """

    host, port = self.client_address[:2]
    return socket.getfqdn(host)
```

That call to getfqdn is the (slow) culprit:

```
In [1]: import socket
In [2]: %time socket.getfqdn("10.0.2.2")
CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 0 ns, total: 0 ns
Wall time: 1.56 s
Out[2]: '10.0.2.2'
```

After I added the "10.0.2.2 10.0.2.2" line to `/etc/hosts` in my guest machine, hostname resolution was near instant:

```
In [3]: %time socket.getfqdn("10.0.2.2")
CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 0 ns, total: 0 ns
Wall time: 834 µs
Out[3]: '10.0.2.2'
```

Note that your gateway address can be found by running `route -n` in your guest environment.

Comment: In my case, ```route -n``` showed ```10.0.2.2``` to ```1.2.3.0```. :)